# Concatenating a range while removing duplicate values as well as specific values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, unique, textjoin

I have a sheet that looks something like this:

[image]

What I'd like to be able to do is concatenate this range while removing duplicate values, but also excluding certain other values.

For example: I'd like to be able to see cat once (note it is in the sheet twice), but not see Mouse at all (also in the sheet twice).

It would also be great if I could do this while also adding a space in between each concatenated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A:A), "mouse")))))
```

[image: 0]

if you want to exclude more values do:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A:A), "mouse|tree")))))
```

if your dataset contains numbers do:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(LOWER(A:A)), 
 "mouse|tree|1238")))))
```

Comment: Okay, so that worked, however I've run into another issue. I assume this is because I'm using strings of text, but the remove duplicates isn't working for me:

https://i.imgur.com/4BegC22.png

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ctrGxIx_HXom9jeywpiTHmbYnXdKOVs8sOyGARL3EM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=join(" " ,Unique(filter(A:A, A:A<>"Mouse")))
```

Change range to suit.